# Confirmation Dialogs in Yosemite

Tags: macos

In Mavericks and lower, when a confirmation dialog, such as [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyoE3.png], popped up, there were 2 states.  The button that would be activated if you hit the space bar and the one that would be activated when you hit return.

Now that I'm on Yosemite, it still works the same but there is no highlight on the focused button that would be activated on spacebar.  See [image: http://note.io/1sQXQ0o]

Anyone know if this is a design feature or a bug?

Comment: in my case that button highlight is present on my iMac, but not on my MacBook, both running the same version of yosemite. It's really annoying, I really don't like the bluish border

Comment: :) I've figured it out, just do the opposite of this - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13833?locale=en_US